# adding value if key is same in hashmap arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am having trouble in adding the values of hashmap arraylist if the key is same. I have an arraylist as

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> expense = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

The output is as

{food = 300},

{entertainment = 100},

{food = 500}

I want to create a new hashmap arraylist

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> newExpense = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

and store

{food= 800},

{entertainment = 100}

I have tried nested loop and all but it didnot work. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Why do you have that List of HashMaps at all? A simple `HashMap<String, Integer>` (With the item name as key) seems to fit your requirements much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a simple hashmap for that...

while putting the values in hashmap, use this code..

```
if (map.containsKey(key))
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + newValue);
    else
        map.put(key, newValue);
```

even though it is not recommended, if you still need to do that because of own reasons..
this could be the logic to get new expenses in a hashmap..

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> expense = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();        
        HashMap<String, Integer> newExpense = new HashMap<>();
        for(HashMap<String, Integer> oldExpense : expense)
        {
            for(String key : oldExpense.keySet())
            {
                if (newExpense.containsKey(key))
                    newExpense.put(key, newExpense.get(key) + oldExpense.get(key));
                else
                    newExpense.put(key, oldExpense.get(key));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newExpense.toString());
```